# Diffrent VSCodeVim behavior when using :edit and `tab` from the original vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vscodevim

I am giving [vscodevim extension](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) a try. However, I'm confused by different behavior when using :edit/:vsplit/:split there. In the original vim, when hitting :edit and `tab` the list of file in the current directory is shown as the picture below:
[image]
However, in vscodeVim, it shows first filename, in this case `iPBlas.cpp` in the directory as in the following piture.
[image]

Does somebody know how to achieve original vim like behavior when using :edit + `tab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you currently have in that Visual Studio Code extension is in line with Vim's default command-line completion behaviour.

The behaviour you are used to in Vim is *not* the default behaviour of command-line completion. It is obtained by enabling `:help 'wildmenu'` and having `list` as the value of `:help 'wildmode'`.

See if the extension supports those options.

---

That extension is not Vim. It is only a partial emulation so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything to work the same. *Especially* if you take customisation into account.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the feature of wildmenu is not implemented yet. https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4541